# Select record between range of datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, select, between

I experiencing trouble with a query. I need to get all record between a range of datetime.

I have the following :

```
select *
from db
where date between '2017-05-02 11:35:31.877' and '2017-05-02 17:06:24.727'
```

I tried with convert, with cast, even with <= and >=, but nothing change.

## EDIT

I tried :

```
select *
from db
where date between cast('2017-05-02 11:35:31.877' as datetime) and cast('2017-05-02 17:06:24.727' as datetime)

select *
from db
where date between convert(datetime,'2017-05-02 11:35:31.877') and convert(datetime,'2017-05-02 17:06:24.727')

select *
from db
where date >= '2017-05-02 11:35:31.877' and  date <= '2017-05-02 17:06:24.727'
```

But absolutely nothing in output. I'm sure that **date is datetime type**

Actually, i'm sure there is record in the table

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

Comment: or post what have you tried, sample data, output and expected output

Comment: Can you explain the issue? Are you getting incorrect rows? Not enough or too many? What is the datatype of your "date" column?

Comment: There seems to be no issues with the query, I am able to get the data. Maybe there are no records within that date range. Are you getting any error ?

Comment: When ever you have an issue try ask with sample data and expected out so that it will be usefull for better answering

Comment: i added some code in the post

Comment: Try inserting a record that is between those two dates and post the code here. Then tell us it doesn't return in the result.

Comment: Can you please try this code and let us know 
`select * from db where date between '2017-05-02 00:00:00.000' and '2017-05-02 23:59:59.999'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by changing the type to datetime2 instead of datetime. Don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your original script.  It will return the values you want, assuming your `date` column is a `datetime` datatype and that you actually have a value stored there that is between your two values.

You can see that this is the case from the following test:

```
declare @db table([date] datetime)
insert into @db values('2017-05-02 11:35:31.877')

select *
from @db
where date >= '2017-05-02 11:35:31.877' and  date <= '2017-05-02 17:06:24.727'
```

Output:

```
date
-----------------------
2017-05-02 11:35:31.877
```

---

## Put simply, you are missing something.

Either your column isn't a `datetime` datatype or you don't have any data that matches your filtering.